# how to convert a list of character containing month_year to a character vector

Tags: r

Need some quick help. I want to convert a list of characters into a single vector I have done this before in the past but have forgotten :(.

```
library(tidyverse)
mth_yr <- purrr::map(2000:2050, ~paste0(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), .x))
```

what I want is a character vector that goes `Jan2000", Feb2000, ...... Dec2050`

I tried using `toString` without any luck.

Comment: What you have there produces a list of vectors, do you need just `unlist(mth_yr)`?

Comment: Not sure if you want to continue using `map` but an alternative is to use `outer`, `month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
year <- 2000:2050;c(outer(month, year, paste0))`

Comment: it is `unlist` thanks, I missed a beat!!!